# How do I make sure in JavaScript that when I click on any checkbox, the input field goes to 0

Tags: javascript, html, go-html-template

How do I make sure that when I click on any checkbox, the input field goes to 0. Because now it works with the first, but not with the others.

This is the code I have now:

```js
let checkbox = document.getElementById("abs");
let inp = document.getElementById("cijfer");
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        inp.value = 0;
    }
});
```

The first input field does go to 0, but the second one does not.

Picture of the problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGIE6.png]

Checkbox and input code in gohtml:

```
<td><input id="cijfer" type="number" name="grade-{{$s.ID}}" step="0.1" min = "0" max = "10" value="{{(index $.Grades $s.ID).Value}}"></td>
            <td>
              <input id="abs" type="checkbox" name="abs-{{$s.ID}}">
              <label for="abs">ABS</label>
            </td>
```

Comment: You're only attaching the event listener to one check box. Have you tried doing the same thing with the other checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

you are using `id` (`getElementById`) and it's an unique attribute!

use "abs" class and "cijfer" class instead!

then find the closest input and make the value zero!

```
<script>
function closest(el, classname) {
   if(el.parentNode){
        if(el.parentNode.className.includes(classname)){
        return el.parentNode;
      }
      else{
        return closest(el.parentNode, classname);
      }
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
}


document.querySelectorAll('.abs').forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('change', function() {
       if (this.checked) {
         let closest = closest(this, 'cijfer');
         closest.value = "0";
        }
     }
});


</script>
```

this was pure js!
you may use jquery instead:

```
$('.abs').on('change', function(){
    $(this).prev('input').val('0');
});
```